# UPDATE MySQL only updating 2 fields - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason the only 2 fields that i am able to update are the first_name & last_name. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried echoing the rest of the fields and they seem to make it through fine. i also receive notice that the query has executed successfully.. thanks!

**EDITED**

HTML FORM

```
<form action="update.php" class="text-center" method="post"> 
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
             <input type="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-   control" placeholder="first name">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
             <input type="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="last name">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
             <input type="address" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="address">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">City:</label>
             <input type="city" name="city" class="form-control" placeholder="city">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="state">State:</label>
             <input type="state" name="state" class="form-control" placeholder="state">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
             <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="phone">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
             <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="xxxx@xxxxx.com">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">Category:</label>
             <input type="category" name="category" class="form-control" placeholder="category">
         </div>
        
         
           <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
   </form>
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
include ('dataBase.php');
include ('functions.php');
$id = $_POST['users'];
echo $id;
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'first_name');
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'last_name');
$address = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'address');
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'city');
$state = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'state');
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'phone');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$category = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'category');
echo $first_name;

$query = "UPDATE customers SET ";
    $query.= "first_name = '$first_name', ";
    $query.= "last_name = '$last_name' ";
    $query.= "address = '$address' ";
    $query.= "city = '$city' ";
    $query.= "state = '$state' ";
    $query.= "phone = '$phone' ";
    $query.= "email = '$email' ";
    $query.= "category = '$category' ";
    $query.= "WHERE id = $id ";

 echo $address;

   try {
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':first_name',$first_name);
$statement->bindValue(':last_name',$last_name);
$statement->bindValue(':address',$address);
$statement->bindValue(':city',$city);
$statement->bindValue(':state',$state);
$statement->bindValue(':phone',$phone);
$statement->bindValue(':email',$email);
$statement->bindValue(':category',$category);
$success = $statement->execute();
$statement->closeCursor();
$message = ($statement == False) ? 'Execute Failed' : 'Execute 
Successful';
echo $message;
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error_message = $e->getMessage();
include('database_error.php');
exit();
}
$statement->closeCursor();
echo $address
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you're repeating `INPUT_POST,'first_name'` often and no idea why you're not using prepared statements throughout your entire code (which is off, I might add). You're not checking for errors here.

Comment: You compile a query which only updates two fields, then you try to use that query as a prepared statement.

Comment: All of your `->bindValue()` calls are pointless. You don't have any placeholders in your query. And since you don't mention getting any error messages, you're probably running in default "silent" mode, and failing to check the DB call return values. If you had been checking, you'd have gotten the boolean FALSE for failure on every single one of the bind calls.

Comment: Placeholders, placeholders, placeholders. RTM http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements - Your question's turning out to be a "don't do this and don't do that" type of "tutorial". Read the manuals before jumping into the deep end.

Comment: *"Tools of the trade"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the query doesn't actually have any parameters to bind to:

```
$query = "UPDATE customers SET ";
$query.= "first_name = '$first_name', ";
$query.= "last_name = '$last_name' ";
$query.= "WHERE id = $id ";
```

In PDO, you have to use the format `?` for non-named parameters, or `:paramater_name` for named parameters. You're using named parameters further down in the script, so your query should be updated to reflect the expected parameters.

Fixing this issue will result in a script which looks something like this:

```
<?php
include ('dataBase.php');
include ('functions.php');
$id = $_POST['users'];
echo $id;
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'first_name');
$last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'last_name');
$address = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'address');
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'city');
$state = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'state');
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'phone');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
$category = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'category');
echo $first_name;

$query = "UPDATE customers SET ";
$query.= "first_name = :firstname, ";
$query.= "last_name = :lastname, ";
$query.= "address = :address, ";
$query.= "city = :city, ";
$query.= "state = :state, ";
$query.= "phone = :phone, ";
$query.= "email = :email, ";
$query.= "category = :category ";
$query.= "WHERE id = :id ";

echo $address;

try {
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':firstname',$first_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':lastname',$last_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':address',$address);
    $statement->bindValue(':city',$city);
    $statement->bindValue(':state',$state);
    $statement->bindValue(':phone',$phone);
    $statement->bindValue(':email',$email);
    $statement->bindValue(':category',$category);
    $statement->bindValue(':id',$id);
    $success = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $message = ($statement == False) ? 'Execute Failed' : 'Execute Successful';
    echo $message;
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include('database_error.php');
    exit();
}
$statement->closeCursor();
echo $address
?>
```

Note also, that I added `$statement->bindValue(':id',$id);`, as the `$id` wasn't being bound in the original code.

Comment: *"The first is that most of your inputs are getting filled with first_name.... (code) ... Updating these to the correct field names should solve that problem."* - OP corrected that, and can be removed.

Comment: I see that. I'll edit it out.

Comment: Wondering why the OP hasn't commented here yet. Or, if they saw your answer to start with.

Comment: @JArnold41 if the solution works, I'd settle for an accept.

Comment: definitely. Thank you for taking the time to help.